# Memory alocation first-fit, best-fit i worst-fit memory managment

Tags: memory

I got a problem with memory location algorithms. I'll have a test from it soon and i keep finding this type of assignment on the tests fom the previous years. I think I'm pretty familier with the concept of memory managment but all the materials I found online describe different type of assignment( with memory blocks and turnaround), in my assignment there's only given 10MB of space, not divaided on any blocks and I honestly got no idea how it works.
It might be something really easy but I'm pretty desperete right now and I could really use some help with it. And sorry for the terribe english and my translation of this assignment, I tried my best

We got a 10MB of physical memory. Simulate memory allocation for the given strategies : first-fit, best-fit and worst-fit for the given events :
P1: assign 6MB,
P2: assign 3MB,
P3: assign 1MB,
P2: dismiss,
P4: assign 2MB,
P1: dismiss,
P5: assign 3MB,
P3: dismiss,
P6: assign 2MB,
P7: assign 1MB.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

> ... in my assignment, there's only given 10MB of space, not divided on any blocks and I honestly got no idea how it works.

That's generally a good starting place for memory allocation. You have one block in the memory arena and it's the size of the entire arena. So your 10M arena has a single 10M block, that happens to be free.

Given the three strategies:

- first fit: use "first" block that's big enough.
- worst fit: use largest block, assuming it's big enough.
- best fit: use smallest block that's big enough.

All those strategies select the exact same block on their first allocation, because there's only one block to choose from.

However, the idea is to then *split* that block, using the first bit to give to the requestor, and creating a block out of the remaining arena for future allocations. That splitting happens every time you choose a block that's larger than the memory requested.

And, in fact, provided you never free, the three strategies will continue to act identically (because there's only ever one free block). But, when you *do* free, you can end up with non-contiguous free blocks in the arena, and that's where the three strategies will start to depart from each other.

Lets look at the first-fit case where we just grab the first block in order that can satisfy the request, and split it. On the right are the resultant blocks with `Pn` indicating an allocated block (`--` is a free block):

```
Megabyte page:  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
                +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
Initial state   |-----------------------------|
P1: assign 6MB  |P1               |-----------|
P2: assign 3MB  |P1               |P2      |--|
P3: assign 1MB  |P1               |P2      |P3|
P2: dismiss     |P1               |--------|P3|
P4: assign 2MB  |P1               |P4   |--|P3|
P1: dismiss     |-----------------|P4   |--|P3|
P5: assign 3MB  |P5      |--------|P4   |--|P3|
P3: dismiss     |P5      |--------|P4   |-----|
P6: assign 2MB  |P5      |P6   |--|P4   |-----|
P7: assign 1MB  |P5      |P6   |P7|P4   |-----|
                +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
Megabyte page:  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
```

Note the coalescing of free blocks at the `P3: dismiss` action. The newly freed `9` and already-free `10` block are now contiguous free blocks so can be combined.

You should also note that it's not necessarily the *lowest* memory address that is considered first (which is why I quoted "first" in the bullet points above).

The free blocks may be in a linked list so, if they new free blocks were added to the *start* of the list, they would be checked in order of most recently freed. This is shown below with the free list on the far right:

```
Megabyte page:  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
                +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
Initial state   |-----------------------------| 10@1
P1: assign 6MB  |P1               |-----------| 4@7
P2: assign 3MB  |P1               |P2      |--| 1@10
P3: assign 1MB  |P1               |P2      |P3| none
P2: dismiss     |P1               |--------|P3| 3@7
P4: assign 2MB  |P1               |P4   |--|P3| 1@9
P1: dismiss     |-----------------|P4   |--|P3| 6@1 1@9
P5: assign 3MB  |P5      |--------|P4   |--|P3| 3@4 1@9
P3: dismiss     |P5      |--------|P4   |-----| 2@9 3@4
P6: assign 2MB  |P5      |--------|P4   |P6   | 3@4
P7: assign 1MB  |P5      |P7|-----|P4   |P6   | 2@5
                +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
Megabyte page:  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
```

The difference there is at the `P6: assign 2MB` and `P7: assign 1MB` stages, where the free list is searched in order rather than attempting to find the lowest address.

---

Now let's contrast that with a best-fit strategy, where you search all free blocks and select the smallest one that can satisfy the request:

```
Megabyte page:  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
                +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
Initial state   |-----------------------------|
P1: assign 6MB  |P1               |-----------|
P2: assign 3MB  |P1               |P2      |--|
P3: assign 1MB  |P1               |P2      |P3|
P2: dismiss     |P1               |--------|P3|
P4: assign 2MB  |P1               |P4   |--|P3|
P1: dismiss     |-----------------|P4   |--|P3|
P5: assign 3MB  |P5      |--------|P4   |--|P3|
P3: dismiss     |P5      |--------|P4   |-----|
P6: assign 2MB  |P5      |P6   |--|P4   |-----|
P7: assign 1MB  |P5      |P6   |P7|P4   |-----|
                +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
Megabyte page:  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
```

That's actually identical to the first first-fit (but not the second first-fit) strategy because it so happens that the best fit was also the lowest address in all cases.

---

And, finally, a worst-fit strategy where, again, you search all free blocks, but select the largest one that can satisfy the request:

```
Megabyte page:  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
                +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
Initial state   |-----------------------------|
P1: assign 6MB  |P1               |-----------|
P2: assign 3MB  |P1               |P2      |--|
P3: assign 1MB  |P1               |P2      |P3|
P2: dismiss     |P1               |--------|P3|
P4: assign 2MB  |P1               |P4   |--|P3|
P1: dismiss     |-----------------|P4   |--|P3|
P5: assign 3MB  |P5      |--------|P4   |--|P3|
P3: dismiss     |P5      |--------|P4   |-----|
P6: assign 2MB  |P5      |P6   |--|P4   |-----|
P7: assign 1MB  |P5      |P6   |--|P4   |P7|--|
                +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
Megabyte page:  | 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
```

The only difference there is at the `P7: assign 1MB` stage where you place it in the 2MB free slot rather than the 1MB free slot.

---

So that's basically the difference, keeping in mind that the actual algorithms for the three strategies may differ slightly to what I've shown here (such as "first" being either first in the free list or lowest address).

But it should hopefully be relatively simply to adapt this answer to any minor variation due to that.